# Is there a shorter form for Go for range loops

Tags: loops, for-loop, go, range

I have checked the language spec - is there a simpler way to say this:

```
for _, month := range []int{4,6,9,11} {
    fmt.Print(month, " ")
}
```

I'm (ideally) looking for something like (I know this isn't Go)

```
for month in [4,6,9,11] {
    fmt.Print(month, " ")
}
```

I know I can do:

```
days30 := []int{4,6,9,11} 
for i := range days30 {
    fmt.Print(days30[i], " ")
}
```

But this is less readible...

Note: This is for teaching purposes - so I'm looking for a simple, self contained solution for students - nothing too advanced please.

Comment: There is no other way. You could of course write your own but given the lack of generics it would either need reflect or it would work for only specific types.

Comment: Sorry, no real help for your question, but one thing you may want to remember when teaching the `range` statement to students is that it has slightly different syntax when ranging on a channel, as a channel has no concept of "index". `for v := range chan` vs. `for k, v := range sliceOrStringOrMap`. https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for

Comment: The last form is perfectly readable. Teaching students to worry about syntax minutiae seems unproductive. Show them idiomatic go.

Comment: Thank you everyone - I did think I couldn't find a simpler method - and it seems I'm (unfortunately) correct. It's not a big problem though - Go has some really nice features that we need.
Thank you Intermernet - I am aware of the channels options - that is a bit later in the course.
Thank you as well JimB - though my learning focus is on Concurrent and Parallel Systems. I'm not just teaching Go, I'm using Go as a example of CSP. They also know Java and C#/C++.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Hesitated to up-vote at first, but there really isn't a simpler answer. +1

Comment: Please add some more information. One word answers, although correct, aren't really worth much. An explanation of the range syntax, or the blank identifier would have probably helped the OP more than just "No".

Comment: @Intermernet It seems like OP already knows how range syntax works; there is no point in explaining it again.

Comment: @FUZxxl, The OP is obviously some form of teacher. I always think it's worth taking the time to properly educate the educators. If they had asked "Should the `subtle.ConstantTimeCompare` function panic on comparing slices of different lengths?" the answer would apparently be "Yes". but they would have no knowledge of the "why" of the situation. I know this is a *much* simpler question, but I think it deserves more than "No". The OP has probably has garnered more info from the first comment (not mine) than the answer.

Comment: How did you manage to bypass the minimum word count for your answer? lol. +1 just for the hell of it.

Comment: @rayryeng there's no minimum word count, only a minimum character count, and invisible separators count towards that quota.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no. Using range on a slice will always either yield the index or index,value.